# matplotlib different values on the xaxis than size

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a graph which represents an array called 'results'.
results size is 50.
When I use plot with 'results' the xAxis is showing values from 0 to 50 like so:
[image: plot using 'results']
I want it to be the values in range [0.02, 0.98] with jumps of 0.02 (50 of them).
How can I do it? I know plt.xlim only limits the results to the given range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `plt.plot(np.arange(50)*0.02, results)`

Comment: it didn't do anything

Comment: This is actually the right answer as np.arange(50)*0.02 set the xaxis as 50 point with dx=0.02 and results should be your plot, of course you also have to execute plt.show() afterward, if this is not working still, please post the actual code you are using so we can provide further guidance

Answer (score 2):

Define your `x`-values by hand:

```
plt.plot(np.linspace(0.02, 0.98,50), results)
```